# Error when build a simple maven project which depends on another simple project in eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I created two most simple eclipse maven projects, one is **test1**, and the other is **test2**.
Project **test1** contains just a 'say hello' static main method in it's only class Main.java. 
Project **test2** contains also nothing but a static main method invoking **test1**'s 'say hello' method, in its only class Main.java. 
Of cause, in Project **test2**'s pom.xml, declares a **dependency on test1**.
That's it! 
Sure I can build project **test1** successfully with 'maven clean package', and run OK. 
But when I tried to build **test2** with 'maven clean package', it gave out error:

> "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test2: Could not resolve dependencies for project test:test2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact test:test1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
>   "

I know if I run '**mvn install**' with **Test1**, everything would be OK, but I just do NOT want to install Test1 into local maven repository, I want to make it dependable in **local workspace**, how can I do that? Anything wrong with me?

BTW, If I open the **'Maven Repositories'** view in eclipse, I can see **'test1 - jar'** is already there under **'Local Repositories'-->'Workspace Projects'** , that means the jar is already installed in Eclipse's workspace repository. And it's very strange that the **'test2 - jar'** is also there existing, though 'mvn package' failed.

Comment: You could bind the resources plugin to the package phase of Test1 to copy the jar created to your test2 lib folder (assuming this lib folder is on the classpath of Test2): https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html   Beware though as the standard way is what maven does right now, i.e. installing test1 to your local repository, and then pulling the dependency in Test2

Comment: yes I understand what you mean, with your suggestion I'll have to add much in pom.xml for each depending jar. <br/> However I think there should be some other better choice. If I open the **'Maven Repositories'** view in eclipse, I can see  **'test1 - jar'** is already there under 'Local Repositories'-->'Workspace Projects' , that means the jar is already installed in Eclipse's workspace repository.

Comment: Your other possibility is to include on the classpath of test2, the test1 jar (and its dependencies that are not included in test2). Still pretty tedious compared to the standard maven way though

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Maven plugin m2e has a feature called "Workspace Resolution". If you enable it, you can directly use the results of other projects in the workspace. You can see that it works if you open the "Maven Dependencies" folder in your Eclipse project. There, you can see a folder symbol in front of the other project (instead of the usual binary symbol for other jars).

Workspace Resolution can be enabled globally (in the preferences) or per project (Right click -> Maven -> Enable Workspace Resolution).